# Dropdown menu does not close after inside link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a navbar. By default the dropdown-content: display: none;
If I hover on a dropdown button it displays the dropdown-content.
When the dropdown-content opens, there are many links that I want, and when I click on one the dropdown-content closes.
Up to now is good.

But the problem comes when I switch to a touchscreen.

I am using GoogleChrome.

So when the screen is a touchscreen, the menu opens on click (not on hover), but when I click on a link inside of it the dropdown-content stays opened and I want it to be closed after a click.

I have tried "hide" and "display: none" methods but after using these methods the default on :hover does not work only after refreshing the page.
That's maybe working someway but I did not find simple solution. I think there must be a very simple solution.

I uploaded the navbar to JSFIDDLE: [navbar click problem on touchscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/varjuhead/cjwva70h/2/)

At Jsfiddle the problem does not seem so try it with Chrome.

I tried to solve it with jQuery toggle() but it makes the solution more complex what I do not want if it possible.

So how to close the the dropdown-content with click on a link on a touchscreen?

```css
<style>
/*NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/
#home {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: solid black 5px;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -470px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: solid orange 5px;
  border-top: solid orange 5px;
  border-right: black solid 5px;
  border-left: black solid 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  
}
.navbar a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdownmy {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: solid black 3px;
}
.dropdownmy .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: black 5px solid;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdownmy:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 1s;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
.dropdown-content .menuheader {
  background: orange;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
.dropdownmy:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.menucolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
.menucolumn a {
  float: none;
  color: black;;
  border-bottom: groove orange 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.menucolumn a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.menurow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .menucolumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .navbar a {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .dropdownmy {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #home {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .dropdownmy .dropbtn {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar a {
    border-bottom: groove black 3px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .varosunkbottomborder {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .dropdownmy {
    border: none;
  }
}
.forborder {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: solid 8px grey;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 25px;
}


/*NAVBAR MENU ENDS*/
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cigánd Város Honlapja</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/cigand.logo.png">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" id="home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#news" class="acolor">NEWS</a>
    <div class="dropdownmy">
        <button class="dropbtn">GOVERNMENT 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="hideit">
            <div class="menuheader">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>   
            <div class="menurow">
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <img src="images/menu.picture.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 2</h6>
                <a href="#">Link1</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdownmy" style="border-bottom: none;">
        <button class="dropbtn">TOWN
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="menuheader">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>   
            <div class="menurow">
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <img src="images/menu.picture.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 2</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I would append my question!
I write some jQuery code that I said and now you will see that another problem arises.

The toggle code is the next:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button1").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-content1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
/*NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/
#home {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: solid black 5px;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -470px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: solid orange 5px;
  border-top: solid orange 5px;
  border-right: black solid 5px;
  border-left: black solid 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  
}
.navbar a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdownmy {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: solid black 3px;
}
.dropdownmy .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: black 5px solid;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdownmy:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 1s;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
.dropdown-content .menuheader {
  background: orange;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.dropdownmy:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.menucolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
.menucolumn a {
  float: none;
  color: black;;
  border-bottom: groove orange 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.menucolumn a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.menurow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .menucolumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .navbar a {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .dropdownmy {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #home {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .dropdownmy .dropbtn {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar a {
    border-bottom: groove black 3px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .varosunkbottomborder {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .dropdownmy {
    border: none;
  }
}
.forborder {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: solid 8px grey;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 25px;
}






/*NAVBAR MENU ENDS*/
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cigánd Város Honlapja</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/cigand.logo.png">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" id="home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#news" class="acolor">NEWS</a>
    <div class="dropdownmy">
        <button class="dropbtn button1">GOVERNMENT 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content dropdown-content1">
            <div class="menuheader">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>   
            <div class="menurow">
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <img src="images/menu.picture.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 2</h6>
                <a class="button1">Link1</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdownmy" style="border-bottom: none;">
        <button class="dropbtn">TOWN
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="menuheader">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>   
            <div class="menurow">
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <img src="images/menu.picture.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 2</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menucolumn">
                <h6 class="forborder">Category 3</h6>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

With Chrome browser and with touchscreen the following problem exists.
When the page is refreshed and first click on the GOVERNMENT button the dropdown-content is showed and suddenly disappear without human intervention. After that, works as I would. This phenomenon happens only at the first contact with the dropdown button and after when the button is opened and after click outside the navbar to close the dropdown-content so and after that click again to the dropdown button.

What would I have to do to eliminate that fast show and disappear because like so the user has to click again to open the menu?

I think the problem exists because the :hover and toggle used at the same time and on a different type of screen(touchscreen and traditional)
The jQuery script would work but I do not have an idea of how to solve this glint problem.

The original problem was that and I hoped that there is an easy solution without a script.
This script solution would be good and simple but there is another problem arose.

If you run this code snippet the problem does not seem.

```
Open with your browser to see:
```

[On google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVK5voyZWTU8vO7GSbBqt2EtrKxGadZX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it's a way easier to use javascript and toggle class on click event `div.classList.toggle("visible");`. I'd say all only css solutions you can find won't be clear and require writing more code

Comment: Could you write a CSS solution?

Comment: I've seen only click solutions using chekboxes

Comment: Just saying that if it's supposed to be a link to other page you won't have this problem, now it's an anchor link